# phonegap device ready not fired when site redirects

Tags: cordova

i need your help , for below scenario ,

i am going to convert mobile site in to the mobile app so i decide to use phonegap.

```
from index.html i redirect to the mobile site domain using  meta tag
Ex: <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT='2;URL=http://m.test.com/testApp.jsp'>
```

it works fine . but i need to do some additional functionality like  track back button        ,notification,contact list that's why i need device ready function which is not firing in above scenario

please provide me any suggestion like how i can call device ready function from my server side jsp or any new idea.

below is my example .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
               <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT='2;URL=http://m.test.com/testApp.jsp'>
               <script src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      function onDeviceReady()
      {
         alert("test");
      }

      </script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget the meta tag. Put your code inside the onDeviceReady function:

```
function onDeviceReady()
      {
         //alert("test");
         document.location = "http://m.test.com/testApp.jsp";
      }
```

But perhaps your approach is not the best, better the [Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying me .. i tried your solution but its not working.it calls the url but not trigger back button event

Comment: below is the example...                                               function onDeviceReady() {
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
      document.location = "http://m.test.com";
    }
    
    function onBackKeyDown()
    {
        alert("test");
    }

Comment: which gives the error.....Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at null

Comment: When you change the document location you LOSE all the javascript code from the referer. The application is in another page.

As I mentioned in the Answer you need a diferent approach: SPA.  Load the second page from AJAX or something.